# Ruby NTLM Library

Tags: ruby, ntlm

Anyone have a good NTLM library recommend for Ruby?

There is http://rubyforge.org/projects/rubyntlm/ but it has not been touched in quite a while.

**Update**: I forgot to point out that I am looking for a client library. The service I want to use sits behind NTLM.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use maybe [rack-ntlm](http://github.com/lukefx/rack-ntlm) could be useful.

I use NTLM for login at the intranet at work but I ended up going with setting up Apache with winbind. I used [this guide](http://blog.rayapps.com/2008/12/02/ntlm-windows-domain-authentication-for-rails-application/) for the rails intregration.

I used these guides for configuration winbind, http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/WindowsActiveDirectory and http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mod_auth_ntlm_winbind.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I should have been more clear in my original question that I was looking for a library to help authenticate against an existing NTLM server (client authentication instead of server authentication).

Comment: The rubyntlm gem above has a client auth example in the download. Look in examples/http.rb

Set the $user, $passwd, $host and $port vars to see if you can access it :) Also has examples for imap/smtp.

Answer (score 1):

Try this gem
    https://rubygems.org/gems/httpi-ntlm

```
gem install httpi-ntlm
```

It worked well for us with SharePoint 2007 and 2010 over NTLM.

```
require 'httpi-ntlm'
request = HTTPI::Request.new("http://example-ntlm-url")
request.auth.ntlm("username", "password")
response = HTTPI.get request
puts response.body
```

Make sure the `[httpi][1]` gem is not loaded prior to loading httpi-ntlm. Otherwise, the HTTPI class from httpi gem gets loaded and the `auth.ntlm` method will not be found.